# Is it required to map account table while doing login process

Tags: mysql, web-applications, authentication

I have two table

**user_details**

```
 user_id               | int(11)                           |
 role_id               | tinyint(4)                        |      
 account_id            | int(11)                           |
 username              | varchar(200)                      |
 password              | varchar(250)                      |
 is_locked             | varchar(1)                        |
 is_account_active     | varchar(1)                        |
```

**account_details**

```
account_id             | int(11)
account_name           | varchar(100)
address                | varchar(200)
is_account_active      | tinyint(1)
```

I want to block all user once they account has been blocked. So they can't able to login into my application.

I have add `is_account_active` column to user table so that i can avoid the joining of  `account_details` table  while user login into application.

Is this good practice to do.

Comment: It looks denormalized with account_id up in user_details

Comment: I have enormous amount users and account. In avg each account will have 10,000 users and i have 1 million accounts.

Comment: Greetings please describe the relationship of users and accounts better in question area so people can help. The one to many or many to many

Comment: In particular can a user ever have more than 1 account. How many users? If a user has an account locked then what is the process of them being allowed to login and at least see a hello screen